# Does Extjs Combobox work with store filters?

Tags: extjs, filter, combobox, grid, store

i want to ask you if extjs comboboxes use filtered stores. I have a table with different kind of business(so it has a "type" field). I have a view with multiple comboboxes, and i want that those works with stores that use the same model, but with different filters. So when i put them to work, it doesn't work.

This is one of the filtered stores:

```
Ext.define('myapp.store.ListaAerolineas', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'myapp.model.Empresa'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'myapp.model.Empresa',
        storeId: 'MyJsonPStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://myapp.localhost/empresa/listar/',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'listaempresa'
            }
        },
        filters: {
            property: 'IdTipo',
            value: 5
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
});
```

This is the model:

```
Ext.define('myapp.model.Empresa', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

idProperty: 'Id',

fields: [
    {
        name: 'Id',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'Nombre',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Direccion',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Telefono',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Contacto',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Celular',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'TipoEmpresa',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Estado',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'FechaCreacion',
        type: 'date'
    },
    {
        name: 'IdTipo',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'IdEstado',
        type: 'int'
    }
]
});
```

And finally this is my grid column definition for my combobox:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'Aerolinea',
    text: 'Aerolinea',
    editor: {
    xtype: 'combobox',
    id: 'cmbGridListaEmbarquesAerolinea',
    store: 'ListaAerolineas'
}
```

So, i must do anything? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

What version of ExtJs are you using? but in general combobox will display only records that are filtered in the store. So, to answer your question - yes, it should work.